# Can I use the spare donut again if needed after it has been filled with Fix a Flat?

Tags: fix-a-flat

I recently had to use a spare donut since I got a flat tire.  I was stranded on the road and my spare donut did not have much air.  Someone helped me and changed the flat tire with the donut and filled it with 'fix a flat' can.  Now, I have replaced the donut with a new tire.  However, I am not sure if I can use the donut in the future (if ever needed) since it was inflated using fix a flat??  Someone mentioned, once you use fix-a flat, you cannot re-use the same tire.

Comment: "I have replaced the donut with a new tire" your question is a bit confusing. If you replaced the old donut tire that was inflated with faf, then you are good to go.

Comment: @Moab - The question is about the donut and reusing it as a spare with F-A-F in it, versus getting a new donut. The OP still wants a viable spare ... still usable or replace it?

Comment: Yes ..as Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 mentioned...I want to ensure that my spare tire is still usable if I ever have to use it in future

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can use it again. The places that change tires try to discourage people from using fix-a-flat because it makes a mess when they go to remove a tire, but it doesn't take away from the integrity of the tire.

That being said, it's probably a good call to keep another can of fix-a-flat in the trunk. In my experience, fix-a-flat doesn't do a great job at fixing flat tires, though what it does do a good job of is inflating tires that have slow leaks. Since your spare was flat, it probably has a slow leak, and when you go to use it again, it might be flat. If that happens, you can just use the extra can of fix-a-flat to inflate it again.

Best of luck!